# Spring data jpa 'don't flush the Session after an exception' occurs after migrating to hibernate 5.x from 4.3

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot with spring data jpa, i am persisting entity having auto generated and one unique field as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ENTITY")
public class Entity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Long entityId;

    @Column(name="data",unique=true)
    private Long data;
}
```

So while saving entity with null entityId(As it is autogenerated) and duplicate data field it thows

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'DL783E6D8D' for key 'UK_htwi98cnnh794ddgu2dic3nm1'
```

that is handled with try catch block as follows

```
try{

//Save operation with null entityId
saveEntity(entity);
}catch(DataIntegrityViolationException)
{
   //Here I am fetching other entity 
}
```

saveEntity function uses spring `@Transaction` with rollback for `DataIntegrityViolationException`

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
public void saveEntity(Entity entity)
{
    entityRepository.save(entity);
}
```

They whole setup was working fine till I migrated to hibernate 5.0.9, after migration it given error as

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in Entity entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

Comment: Hibernate has always documented the fact that exceptions are not recoverable, and that the only safe thing to do after an exception is to rollback the transaction and close the session, which can't be used anymore. If it worked before, it was an accident. Don't try to reuse the session after it throws an exception.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry I have missed the transaction and rollback..I have updated the question

Comment: If you're calling the saveEntity method from another transactional method, then all the code is still being executed in the same transaction, using the same session.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet removed Transactional from the method that calls saveEntity. That resolved the issue.Please add your above comment in answer I will accept it.